# How to redirect to another route with When i submit a form in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-routing

I have attribute for filter route. when I submit a form I want redirect to another controller with a filter attribute.

My filter attribute name is spam attribute. Now I have a code for change route

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Error", action = "Index", ErrorCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, Handler = "Controller" }));

    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}
```

Now when I submit a form my filter is correct fine and I can redirect to Error controller but my page not change or not execute error page for me.

**The problem is that the previous page stays**
and
**In the meantime, I've used Ajax Begin Form to submit form**

Comment: The whole point of ajax is to stay on the same page. If you want to redirect, the do not use ajax.

Comment: that,s right  Stephen Muecke. Thank You....